# Remote control to my Android mobile Without internet

Tags: android, remote-desktop, connection

I have an Android mobile and a Ubuntu laptop. I want to remotely connect to the mobile from the laptop through the local network, without using Internet. How I can connect to my Android mobile locally without Internet? I had similar tools in Windows, so how can I do the same in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please, specify the tool you used in Windows to do this.

Comment: scrcpy did the trick well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.maketecheasier.com/cast-android-screen-linux-desktop/) looks promising. It shows both how to do it over WiFi and over USB.

Edit: [This](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/control-android-devices-from-your.html) might actually be better, since I assume (from the title) that you actually want to control the mobile.